# iOS Google Analytics, I still see logs after setDry to YES

Tags: objective-c, ios8, google-analytics-api

I have set dryRun to YES

```
#if DEBUG
[[GAI sharedInstance] setDryRun:YES];
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
#endif
```

but still see logs like this

```
2014-10-03 08:58:09.933 HelloWorld[85791:677983] VERBOSE: GoogleAnalytics 3.09 -[GAIBatchingDispatcher persist:] (GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:431): Saved hit: {
    parameters =     {
        "&_crc" = 0;
        "&_u" = ".1111";
        "&_v" = "mi3.0.9";
        "&a" = 941551484;
        "&aid" = "co.helloworld.ios";
        "&an" = "HelloWorld";
        "&av" = "1.0";
        "&cd" = "Test Test";
        "&cid" = "ca931366-1111-483b-bbcc-111111111111";
        "&sr" = 320x568;
        "&t" = screenview;
        "&tid" = "UA-11111111-1";
        "&uid" = "87492A55-98E4-4FF7-1111-111111111111";
        "&ul" = en;
        "&v" = 1;
        "&z" = 4381801786046188211;
        gaiVersion = "3.09";
    };
    timestamp = "2014-10-03 05:58:09 +0000";
}
```

Where is my fault? How can I disable `GAS` for debug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try to `setDispatchInterval` to negative or/and set `optOut` to `true`.